# Issue with ranking observations from a txt file in C

Tags: c, rank

I have the following code which reads in a txt file of numbers and I need one column which gives the numbers themselves and another which gives the ranks of these numbers. However, I'm getting a very weird result. The first half of the numbers are 0 besides the first observation. Then the latter half of the numbers are okay. When I print the numbers before performing the ranking algorithm, everything looks fine, so something about the ranking algorithm is altering the numbers, but I'm not sure why that could be occurring. The contents of the txt file can be seen below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  30.00 71.51  3.30 87.44 53.42 63.16 89.10 25.75 93.16 27.72
  71.58 48.34 53.11 18.34 27.13 60.31 83.34 22.81 66.84 52.91
  53.42 15.22  8.01 53.39 76.12 79.09 67.61 38.39 24.81 73.21
  13.42 52.10 34.86 99.83 38.46 81.59 61.75 79.62 93.39  3.21
  99.34 92.22 94.29  7.03  6.67 89.35 83.14  9.01 12.68 62.22
   2.95 85.02 95.82 73.96 49.29 77.72 36.65  3.48 48.98 71.83
   1.41  9.48 30.00 89.95 28.39 79.36 54.05 46.08 11.67 37.78
  77.17 74.33 10.13  4.62 49.95 68.40 19.40 34.06  4.11 98.40
  42.44 64.14 89.41 52.99 71.79  3.94 19.73 44.91 71.44 59.10
  27.54 15.67 67.95 55.61 26.05 25.01 82.09 89.67 57.08 38.27
```

My code is as follows.

```
int main()
{
    // Rank data

    double vec2[]={};
    int l;
    l=0;
    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("/Users/remymacdonald/Dropbox/STAT778_S20_Shared/Homework/HW1.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp2, "%lf", &vec2[l]) != EOF){l++;};

    // check that it's working

    for(int loop = 0; loop < 100; loop++)
        printf("%lf\n", vec2[loop]);

    printf("\n\n\n\n");


    int rank[100] = {0};

    int i,j;

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int curRank = 1;
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (vec2[i] > vec2[j]) {
                curRank++;
            } else {
                rank[j]++;
            }
        }

        rank[i] = curRank;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        printf("%lf %d\n", vec2[i],rank[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `double vec2[]={};` Your array has a size of zero.

Comment: Thanks it works now!

Comment: We cannot test run your code with that screenshot...

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Aside: `fscanf(fp2, "%lf", &vec2[l])` in this usage can return **three** possible values: `0` (invalid scan attempt due to non-numeric data), `1` (one item successfully scanned), or `EOF` (end of file), and your code rejects only one of the two values that signify lack of success. So I would write it as `while(fscanf(fp2, "%lf", &vec2[l]) == 1)`

Comment: By rank, you mean the rank if it the vector were placed into a sorted dag with respect to the lowest element?